# AUCTeX: How to enable auto expansion of sub and superscript in custom math environment

Tags: emacs, auctex, reftex

With help from the question [How to add custom math-environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22573/how-can-i-tell-auctex-that-breqn-is-a-math-environment) I taught AUCTeX that `IEEEeqnarray` and its starred counterpart are math environments. I added the following to my `.emacs`

```lisp
;; teach auctex IEEEeqnarray
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'add-my-latex-environments) 
(defun add-my-latex-environments () 
  (LaTeX-add-environments 
     '("IEEEeqnarray" LaTeX-env-label)
     '("IEEEeqnarray*" LaTeX-env-label)))
```

In the `custom-set-variables` section I added

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
'(font-latex-math-environments (quote ("display" "displaymath" "equation" "eqnarray" "gather" "multline" "align" "alignat" "xalignat" "IEEEeqnarray" "IEEEeqnarray*")))
```

And finally made reftex aware of it

```lisp
;; Additionally, reftex code to recognize this environment as an equation 
(setq reftex-label-alist 
  '(("IEEEeqnarray" ?e nil nil t)
    ("IEEEeqnarray*" ?e nil nil t)))
```

There's some more emacs customisation stuff found at [How to Typeset Equations in LaTeX](http://moser.cm.nctu.edu.tw/manuals.html)

Now my question is:

**How can I teach AUCTeX that it should also auto-expand the sub- and superscripts in these custom environments?**

At the beginning of my `.emacs` I set

```lisp
(setq TeX-electric-sub-and-superscript t) ; auto-expand sub- and superscript
```

But even though I integrated the `IEEEeqnarray` environments into AUCTeX with the above customisations, it doesn't auto-expand the `_` and `^` symbols in these environments, as it does in, e.g. `eqnarray`. I love this functionality, and need it in my custom math environments as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electric super and subscripts uses `texmathp` to determine when they should be run.  This function is controlled by the `texmathp-tex-commands` variable which you can customize.  You will need to call `texmathp-compile` if you set it outside of the customize interface.

Adding the following to your `custom-set-variables` and restarting Emacs should do the trick.

```lisp
'(texmathp-tex-commands (quote (("IEEEeqnarray" env-on) ("IEEEeqnarray*" env-on))))
```