# How to have AucTeX auto-complete `\left[ \right]`, `\left( \right)` in custom math environment?

Tags: emacs, auctex

**Note:** This is probably a duplicate, but I can't figure out the right search terms. If you can post the link to the original question and close this one, it would be greatly appreciated.

I followed the advice [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22573/how-can-i-tell-auctex-that-breqn-is-a-math-environment), and now AucTeX has the correct font highlighting and has math mode enabled in my custom math environment. But AucTex doesn't auto-complete `\left[ \right]` or `\left( \right)` in my custom math environment, which is really inconvenient.

> **Question:** How can I change my `.emacs` file to have AucTeX auto-complete `\left[ \right]`, `\left( \right)` in my custom math environment?

For reference, here is my `.emacs`:

```
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
(require 'auto-complete)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'latex-mode) 
(require 'ac-math) 
(defun my-ac-latex-mode () 
   (setq ac-sources
         (append '(;  again, I don't want unicode: ac-source-math-unicode
           ac-source-math-latex
           ac-source-latex-commands)
                 ac-sources)))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-ac-latex-mode)
(ac-flyspell-workaround)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'org-mode)
(require 'auto-complete-config) 
(ac-config-default)
(setq ac-auto-start t)          
(setq ac-auto-show-menu t)
(global-auto-complete-mode t) 
(show-paren-mode 1)
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)
(auto-fill-mode -1)
(remove-hook 'text-mode-hook #'turn-on-auto-fill)
(remove-hook 'text-mode-hook 'auto-detect-wrap)
'(text-mode-hook
  '((lambda nil (auto-fill-mode nil))
    smart-spacing-mode))
(auto-fill-mode nil)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
(setq mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(1 ((shift) . 1)))
(setq mouse-wheel-progressive-speed nil)
(setq mouse-wheel-follow-mouse 't)
(setq scroll-step 1)
(setq mac-mouse-wheel-mode t)
(setq mac-mouse-wheel-smooth-scroll t)
(setq TeX-save-query nil)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)
(require 'smartparens-config)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'smartparens-mode)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'add-my-latex-environments)
(defun add-my-latex-environments ()
  (LaTeX-add-environments
   '("formulae" LaTeX-env-label)))

(custom-set-variables 
 '(font-latex-math-environments (quote  
     ("formulae"))) 
  '(TeX-insert-braces nil))

(setq reftex-label-alist 
  '(("formulae" ?e nil nil t)))
```

Comment: You can use C-c C-m and type `left` and your brace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the following command to your *.emacs* file:

`(setq LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace t)`

Comment: This _almost_ works -- now when I type `\left[ ` it auto-completes to `\left[ ] \right]`, i.e. it auto-completes as both `[]` (which is all it did before) and now _also_ `\left[ \right]`. Same thing with `\left(` -- now it auto-completes to `\left( ) \right)` instead of just `\left( \right)` (what I want and what happens in non-custom math modes) or just `()` (what it was before).

Comment: Do you know of a way to make the other auto-complete function stop inside this environment?

Comment: Also, now outside of any math environment (i.e. just plain text), `\left(` auto-completes to `\left( \right))` (notice the two right-parentheses), and `\left[` auto-completes to `\left[ \right]]`. So the same behavior as in the custom math environment but in the opposite order I guess.

Comment: With me this works as expected, i.e `\left( --> \left ( \right)` even in math mode. So I suspect something wrong in your _.emacs_ file. Try to figure out what you have tried before!!

Comment: After looking in your _.emacs_, I suspect **smartparens-mode**. So try to disable it in latex-mode.

Comment: You're a hero! Yeah that fixed it exactly -- I appreciate it.